# How to embed an Excel file in a Windows.Form with vb.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to open an Excel file from a Windows Form, a Panel, for can read and edit the document.

Is for an application where the users can use the Excel program without realizing that they are really using Excel.

My problem is that I'm only able to open the Excel file in another window, not contained on the form.

The file is stored in local.

Here is the code:

```
Dim MyExcel As New Excel.Application 'open object of Excel for the form
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook 'objeto referring to the workbook
Private Sub OpenFile()
    Dim strURL As String = "C/User/Me/Example.xlsm"

    MyExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(strURL)
    oWB = MyExcel.ActiveWorkbook

    MyExcel.Application.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    MyExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I have another class, where I declare the Panel1, how should I refer for opening the Excel at the Panel1?

I know that with this code, the file opens in Excel app, but what should I do for opening in this interface? Like in the following picture (Sry can't upload)
[http://prntscr.com/gzbo5q][1]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `without realizing that they are really using Excel`, how is that going to happen and why would you want to make the user think its not Excel? Your current code would show Excel being opened and on top of that an Excel instance would pop up under processes.

Comment: Cause users interac with my program made in Excel, but its protected to any dangerous modification and the interface doesn't seem Excel. That's why I dont want that, when they open the application with the '.exe', the MS Excel opens. Instead of that, I want to show the Excel file in the Windows form, made with the vb.net. Thank you.

Comment: From your code it seems you want to open Excel (maybe embed it in your form), but from your comment it seems like you want to now populate elements in your web form (like a table, with cells) with the data in the Excel cells. Can you show an example of what you are trying to do, maybe with a diagram/picture?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I wanna embed it on a Windows Form like a Panel, and display the MS Excel program there. Something like this: [link] (http://prntscr.com/gznmzg) As you can see on the previous link, the Form contains the Excel file, and have some buttons for doing extra functionalities. Thank you @MahendranNadesan

Comment: Then I think you should edit your question to reflect this. Searching for "embed excel in winform" seems to return results you can go through. Please though, look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @inhaki Please look through this sample:
 http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/07/02/embed-excel-documents-in-vb-net-application/[link]